# How can I check the user's system time against the actual time and conditionally update it?

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-async

How can I check the user's system time (easy) against the "real" time (their time may be set wrong) and then inform them and offer to update their system time to the actual time and then do so?

IOW, pseudocode:

```
DateTime dtSet = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dtActual = GetActualTime();
if (dtSet != dtActual) // allow some delta, such as anything under a 1 minute variance)
{
  if (UserAllowsChange())
  {
    ChangeTheTimeTo(dtActual);
  }
}
```

Maybe Noda Time is in my future. I can't help it, but every time I see that name, I think of the song by Don Williams/Eric Clapton.

Comment: Isn't that functionality build into the operating system?

Comment: ? I'm talking about doing it programmatically. IOW, the "ChangeTheTimeTo()" method is the one I need help with/suggestions on.

Comment: @mydogisbox Yes, but only if it works. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A process must have the `SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME` privilege to set the system time.  A Windows Store app will never have this privilege.  Windows Store apps run in a sandbox, called an app container, and are limited in how they can interact with the rest of the system.

From an ordinary desktop app that has sufficient privileges, [`SetSystemTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724942.aspx) may be used to set the system time.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to James McNellis' answer...DateTime.Now uses the local system time. You need to connect to a Network Time Server (NTS) to get the "real" time. You can then parse the response from the NTS as a DateTime structure, and compare against DateTime.Now.

If they do not match, you can then use [SetSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724942.aspx) (provided you have priviledges) to set the time given by the NTS.

Bear in mind that say for example you get the NTS response, parse it, and then set the system time, the new local system time will still be wrong because of the elapsed time it took between getting the NTS response and setting the system time.

You might want to consider using something like Timespan or Stopwatch to monitor the elapsed time between getting the NTS response and setting the system time. adding this to the NTS response should give a more accurate result.

Check this out (connecting to an NTS)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17851/Connecting-To-A-Network-Time-Server

http://www.dotnet-snippets.com/dns/c-simple-network-time-ntp-protocol-client-SID571.aspx